# Python Pandas Group Dataframe by Column / Sum Integer Column by String Column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, xlsxwriter

I have been stuck all day and have been through numerous SO articles and am still stuck on my last final piece. I imported a CSV into a massive dataframe, then eventually got the smaller dataframe below: (Note: My df is indexed on 'Name' right now, which is what I need to base the group or sum off of)

```
  Name          Classification       Value 1     Value 2
Company 1   Classification Code 1      5000       8000      
Company 1   Classification Code 1      6000       2000
Company 2   Classification Code 1      2000       3000    
Company 2   Classification Code 1      1000       4500     
Company 3   Classification Code 2      15000      10000      
Company 3   Classification Code 2      20000      32000     
Company 4   Classification Code 3      7500       10000    
Company 4   Classification Code 3      7000       1500
```

What I am struggling with now is how to sum the two values based on the company (I have mainly been using groupby and sum() but have been stuck for hours. I know there are a lot of SO articles talking about summing things in pandas but I have had no luck for hours. ANY help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much.

Edit:
The output I am looking for is the following

```
Company 1    Classification Code 1    11,000    10,000
Company 2    Classification Code 1    3,000      7,500
Company 3    Classification Code 2    35,000    42,000
Company 4    Classification Code 3    14,500    11,500
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**
*`set_index` then `groupby`*
This assumes that the `'Classification'` column is the same across `Company`

```
df.set_index('Classification', append=True) \
    .groupby(level=[0, 1]).sum().reset_index(1)

                  Classification  Value 1  Value 2
Name                                              
Company 1  Classification Code 1    11000    10000
Company 2  Classification Code 1     3000     7500
Company 3  Classification Code 2    35000    42000
Company 4  Classification Code 3    14500    11500
```

**Option 2**
*`groupby` then `agg`*
This doesn't make any assumptions about uniqueness of `'Classification'` across `'Company'` but will just grab the first `'Classification'` per `'Company'`

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg(
    {'Classification': 'first', 'Value 1': 'sum', 'Value 2': 'sum'})

                  Classification  Value 1  Value 2
Name                                              
Company 1  Classification Code 1    11000    10000
Company 2  Classification Code 1     3000     7500
Company 3  Classification Code 2    35000    42000
Company 4  Classification Code 3    14500    11500
```

---

**Response to Comments**
*In regards to concatenation*
Check `dtypes` with `df.dtypes`.  If you see `object` instead of `int` then yes, you need to convert to `numeric`.

You can do this simply with

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore').groupby(level=0).agg(
    {'Classification': 'first', 'Value 1': 'sum', 'Value 2': 'sum'})
```

Or more manually

```
df['Value 1'] = df['Value 1'].astype(int)
df['Value 2'] = df['Value 2'].astype(int)
```

Then proceed to prior suggestions.

*In regards to placement of columns*
You can always reorder your columns

```
d1 = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore').groupby(level=0).agg(
    {'Classification': 'first', 'Value 1': 'sum', 'Value 2': 'sum'})

d1[df.columns]
```

Or

```
d1 = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore').groupby(level=0).agg(
    {'Classification': 'first', 'Value 1': 'sum', 'Value 2': 'sum'})

d1.reindex_axis(df.columns, 1)
```

Comment: @priRSquared thank you very much for the reponse so quickly. This worked as you showed, I will vote this as a complete answer, however I forgot to clarify in the original question that I need to sum both values and show them in the new df. Also, I need to show the classification code (a company will always have the classification code). Again thank you SO much.

Comment: No problem, if you could edit your question to include what you expect the output to look like, I can show you exactly how to get it.

Comment: I just edited the question with my desired output - thank you again

Comment: Two last pieces (I will upvote your answer for this help) that I need assistance with. 1) It seems to be printing/exporting the 'Classication' into the last column, instead of the 1st. 2) For both of these options the 'Value' numbers are not actually summing, it seems that they are concatenating, could this mean my values aren't int?

Comment: That worked perfect, thanks again! I am about to mark this question as answered. Since you know so much though I have one more question. When creating my final df (shown above) I use a parameter of 'Value1' > 0 on the previous df, however negative values are still inserted. Do you know why this might be? Thanks again, marking the question as answered but I thought I would just ask.

Comment: @ls101 When you say that you used the parameter `'Value 1' > 0`... that is too ambiguous.  It would be better to ask a new question where you can clarify exactly what you mean.

Comment: here is the link to the new question I asked, in case you have a moment. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44556966/function-to-insert-only-positive-values-into-pandas-dataframe-results-in-negativ